# How to create a carousel in an android screen to show different elements?

Tags: android, view, screen, carousel, sliding

In an android activity, I would like to have a view that can display different elements, sliding the screen like a carousel.

My question is what is the appropriate view for this work.

Comment: you can use a ViewPager for this, just google it .. you should find many examples .. if you want something like an circle indicator, use Jake Wharton's ViewPagerIndicator Library and you should also be able to find examples of this by googling it.. JUST GOOGLE IT ;) .. I see that your new to stackoverflow, try being more precise with your questions and search them on stackoverflow before asking them or you will get down voted which will decrease your reputation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Horizontal ScrollView(http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) is probably the simplest to implement, but I would suggest you to use a ViewPager (http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try ViewPager. This is the documentation http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html